# How to remove the element from DOM in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to remove the below 3 DOM elements using Jquery based on my custom condition, Please help me , I am new to Jquery. Its not repeat question.
Here is the Image Link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq2a2.jpg

Please help me.

I have tried this, it did not fix the issue -

```
thiz.element.find('input[name=IsGovernment' + thiz.options.customerId + ']).hide();
```

From UI I don't want to see the `Label` and radio button options based on some condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems. First, you mispelled `this`. Instead of `this` you have "thiz" at the the beginning of your code and in the selector.

The other problem is that you have an an incorrect `'` at the end of your selector. An easy way to fix the problem is to use `"` instead of `'` for the entire string inside the selector, and then use `'` for the attribute value inside the attribute selector.

So putting everything together, it should be like this:

```
this.element.find("input[name='IsGovernment" + this.options.customerId + "']").hide();
```

If you want to hide both the `<input>` and its sibling `<span>`, you will need to change the above solution to something like this. Notice this hides the parent `<label>`, so everything inside will be hidden.

```
$("input[name='IsGovernment" + this.options.customerId + "']").parent().hide();
```

Comment: doesn't he need the part after the `=` to be quoted though?  as in: `'input[name="IsGovernment' + this.options.customerId + '"]'`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am able to hide the 'Customer designation',using this code, this.element.find('input[name=IsGovernment' + this.options.customerId + ']').hide();
            this.element.find('label[for=IsGovernment]').hide();But I am still not able to hide the text 'Commercial' and 'Government' from the HTML, Please help me sir

Comment: I have showed the text 'Commercial' and 'Government' from the HTML in the image https://imgur.com/a/3K7dbpH

Comment: @ScottWeaver You're right. I changed it so the attribute name is single quoted. Then, the entire selector uses doubles quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: Hi Scott and ocBiermann, Could you please let me know how to hide the text 'Commercial' and 'Government' from the DOM HTML, as I have showed in the image

Comment: try with the updated answer, i mean that *should* work from a selector perspective...

Comment: I have tried this - this.element.find('Commercial').remove(); it did not work

Comment: Any answer will be much appreciated

Comment: @shank That won't work because you are trying to match the `aria-label` attribute. That's not ideal. I think the problem might be the first part of your statement. Is there any reason why you are using `this.element` ? Why not just use `$("input[name='IsGovernment" + this.options.customerId + "']").hide();` ?

Comment: Hi ocBiermann, Thanks for your kind response, That was worked, Now I am trying to hide the text inside the span element which has displayed as 'Commercial' and 'Government'  in the UI, so I need to Hide these tow text, please help me, I have already showed the DOM element in my image,  here is my DOM element <label>
    <input name="IsGovernment5600" disabled="disabled" id="IsGovernment5600" style="display: none;" aria-label="Commercial" type="radio" value="C">
    <span class="s-panel-label-text">Commercial</span>
   </label>

Comment: even I have tried with $ that also did not work : like  $('Commercial').hide();

Comment: @shank You can modify the code a bit to match both. Notice that the `<span>` is a sibling of the `<input>`. I will update my answer to show a solution that will match both and hide both.

Comment: Hi ocBiermann, Thanks again for your response, I am waiting for your kind solution

Comment: Hi ocBiermann, Thank you so much for your quick response, your solution's worked fine without any issue, once again Thanks for your time sir.